# DynamoDB simple UpdateItem throwing "The provided key element does not match the schema" ValidationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to update a string field in a DynamoDB table (thread1) which only has Hashkey(threadId). Document with threadId = "AA" definitely exists and also has field1 attribute.

I'm getting **"The provided key element does not match the schema"** ValidationException when POST of UpdateItem from API Gateway is invoked using the following Body Mapping Template.

```
{
  "TableName": "thread1",
  "Key": {
    "HashKeyElement": {
      "S": "AA"
    }
  },
  "AttributeUpdates": {
    "field1": {
      "Value": {
        "S": "Worked!"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried the same using UpdateExpression, which also gives the same error.

Comment: Same issue with GetItem POST as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your hashkey column is called 'threadId', your update should look like this:

```
{
  "TableName": "thread1",
  "Key": {
    "threadId": "AA"
  },
  "AttributeUpdates": {
    "field1": {
      "Value": "Worked!"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked after changing it to "Key": {
    "threadId": {
      "S": "AA"
    }